# Return mock data set in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to mimic an API call by using a mock data set. However I want to an existing approach in my project to getting the data.

Here is my code

Interface

```
export interface DefaultEmployeePortfolio {
    id: string;
    category: string;
    value: string;
}
```

Offer Service

```
getDefautltEmployeePortfolio(): Observable<DefaultEmployeePortfolio[]> {
    const token = this._storeService.getStoredData().id_token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    const options = { headers: headers };
    const data = [
      {id: 1, category: 'Risk Rating', value: 'Aggressive'},
      {id: 2, category: 'Portfolio Management', value: 'Active'}
    ];
    return this._http.get<DefaultEmployeePortfolio[]>(data, options);
}
```

TS File

```
this._offerService.getDefautltEmployeePortfolio().subscribe((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
})
```

What would I need to do to get the data from my service into the component(.ts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep it easy to switch from a mock data to a real data then creating a mockable json would be the best approach. Another approach would be to create an observable with the mock data, but that would just add unnecessary logic which you would have to remove once you plug in the real data (coming from an API).

Create a `mock.json` file in your `assets` folder and then reference it in your `http.get`

**service**

```
getDefautltEmployeePortfolio(): Observable<DefaultEmployeePortfolio[]> {
    const token = this._storeService.getStoredData().id_token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    const options = { headers: headers };
    return this._http.get<DefaultEmployeePortfolio[]>('./assets/mock.json', options);
}
```

**mock.json**

```
[
  {"id": 1, "category": "Risk Rating", "value": "Aggressive"},
  {"id": 2, "category": "Portfolio Management", "value": "Active"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fake endpoint to return mock data:**

```
getDefautltEmployeePortfolio(): Observable<DefaultEmployeePortfolio[]> {

  const data: any = [
      {id: 1, category: 'Risk Rating', value: 'Aggressive'},
      {id: 2, category: 'Portfolio Management', value: 'Active'}
    ]
  return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next(data);
          }, 1000);
        });
      }
```